# styling google form radio button

Tags: html, css, google-forms

I'm trying to style google form embedded in my website and i want to change the appearance of radio buttons. Any ideas how can i do that ? i know how to do that with a radio button where label comes first and input second, but here input is wrapped in a label...

html looks like this :

```
<label>
  <span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block">
    <input type="radio" name="entry.1070214158" value="Other" id="group_1070214158_3" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="Other">
  </span>
  <span class="ss-choice-label">Other
  </span>
</label>
```

I want to change default radio button appearance to a custom square with a checkmark if radio is selected. I found this method where radio button is replaced with sprite image of an empty square and when item is selected it shifts the sprite so it looks like you got a checkmark inside square. I would like to know how can i achieve same result with google form radio buttons. This is what i found on the web and tried to implement but without success

```
  <input type="radio" name="details" id="radio1" class="radio" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="radio1" class="radioLabel">Other</label>

input[type=radio].radio {
              position:absolute; 
              z-index:-1000; 
              left:-1000px; 
              overflow: hidden; 
              clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
              height:1px; 
              width:1px; 
              margin:-1px; 
              padding:0; 
              border:0;
            }

            input[type=radio].radio + label.radioLabel {
              padding-left:25px;
              height:17px; 
              display:inline-block;
              line-height:22.5px;
              background-repeat:no-repeat;
              background-position: 0 0;
              vertical-align:middle;
              cursor:pointer;

            }

            input[type=radio].radio:checked + label.radioLabel {
              background-position: 0 -17px;
            }
            label.radiolabel {
        background-image:url(../Img/check.png);
```

Comment: Google forms can be styled as any forms. Check [This](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/6DN8by8QLjQ)

Comment: `label .ss-choice-item-control .ss-q-radio {background-color:red;}`